# Joining tables without keys in common

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following question: would it be possible to join tables with no key in common?
I have 4 datasets:

```
df1
Col1 
214  
...

df2
Col1  
412  

df3
Col1 
421
...

df4
Col1
241
...
```

What I would like to have is the following:

```
df1     df2   df3      df4
Col1   Col1_2 Col1_3  Col_4
214     412   421     241
```

where `df1` has length `100`, `df2` length `99`, `df3` length `212`, `df4` length `21`.

I have though of merge or left join as I want df1 as first column, but they require '`on`'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `concat`

```
df = pd.concat([df1,df2,....], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proof of concept data:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
           'col1':[214,1,2,3]
         })
print(df1)
   col1
0   214
1     1
2     2
3     3

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
           'col1':[412,4,5]
         })
print(df2)
   col1
0   412
1     4
2     5

df3 = pd.DataFrame({
           'col1':[421,6]
         })
print(df3)
   col1
0   421
1     6

df4 = pd.DataFrame({
           'col1':[241]
         })
print(df4)
   col1
0   241
```

You have to use pd.concat, with axis=1 ("ignore_index=True" as optional argument to change the column names)

```
combined_data_frame = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3, df4], axis=1)
print(combined_data_frame)
   col1   col1   col1   col1
0   214  412.0  421.0  241.0
1     1    4.0    6.0    NaN
2     2    5.0    NaN    NaN
3     3    NaN    NaN    NaN

combined_data_frame = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3, df4], axis=1, ignore_index=True)
print(combined_data_frame)
     0      1      2      3
0  214  412.0  421.0  241.0
1    1    4.0    6.0    NaN
2    2    5.0    NaN    NaN
3    3    NaN    NaN    NaN
```